# What am I doing wrong? (PHP and MYSQL)

Tags: php, mysql

I have this code here which I have been using in several projects without any issue. The only thing i've changed is that I am using MAMP instead of XAMPP for this.

The problem I'm facing is the code runs without any errors (it runs through the if else statement in the login functions, but nothing happens (it doesn't redirect the user) and if I input wrong details it shows that no records are found. Can someone guide me through this please?

Login.php

```
<?php
session_start();
if (!empty($_SESSION['admin'])&&!empty($_SESSION['type'])) {
    header("Location: admin/index.php");
}
elseif (!empty($_SESSION['user'])&&!empty($_SESSION['type'])) {
    header("Location: user/");
}
?>


<!--===== LOGIN =====-->
<section id="login" class="padding" style="padding-top: 200px;">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-md-12 text-center">
        <div class="profile-login">
          <div class="login_detail" style="margin-top:-50px;">
            <!-- Tab panes -->
            <div class="tab-content">
             <h1>
                <?php
                    extract($_POST);
                    if (isset($btn) && !empty($username) && !empty($password)) {
                        require 'includes/users.php';
                        login();
                    }
                ?>
            </h1>
              <div role="tabpanel" class="tab-pane fade in active" id="profile">
                <h2>Login Below</h2>
                <div class="agent-p-form">
                  <div class="row">
                    <form class="callus" action="login.php"  method="POST">
                      <div class="col-md-12">
                        <div class="single-query">
                          <input name="username"  type="text" class="keyword-input" placeholder="Username" required>
                        </div>
                        <div class="single-query">
                          <input name="password" type="password" class="keyword-input" placeholder="Password">
                        </div>
                      </div>
                      <div class="col-md-12 col-sm-12 col-xs-12 text-center">
                        <div class="query-submit-button">
                          <button name="btn" type="submit" class="btn_fill">Login</button>
                        </div>
                      </div>
                    </form>
```

Users.php

```
<?php 
function login()
{
  require 'connect.php';
    $username = mysqli_real_escape_string($con,$_POST['username']);
    $password = mysqli_real_escape_string($con,$_POST['password']);
    $pass = $password;
    $sql = "SELECT * FROM `users` WHERE `username`='$username' AND `password`='$pass'";
    $query = mysqli_query($con,$sql);
    $row = mysqli_num_rows($query);
    if ($row == 0) {
        echo "<b style='font-size:12px; color:#FFF'>Wrong Username/Password Combination</b>";
    }
    elseif ($row == 1) {
        $fetch = mysqli_fetch_array($query);
        $type = $fetch['user_role'];
        $name = $fetch['username'];
        if ($type == "Administrator") {
            @session_start();
            $_SESSION['user_role'] = $type;
            $_SESSION['admin'] = $name;
            header("Location: admin/index.php");
        }

        elseif ($type=="User") {
            @session_start();
            $_SESSION['user_role'] = $type;
            $_SESSION['user'] = $name;
            header("Location: user/");
        }

        else{
            echo "<b>Error</b>";
        }
    }
    else{
        echo "<b>Error</b>";
    }
}
```

Comment: Have you tried printing something before the  header("Location: user/"); and  header("Location: admin/index.php");

Comment: What error did you get?

Comment: I'm not getting any error, the page reloads without showing any error,

Comment: @BittoBennichan I have just used this under the user   echo "test"; but it didn't show.

Comment: `@session_start();` — you might get more error messages if you didn't suppress them with `@`!

Comment: please echo something out in  elseif ($type=="User") and if ($type == "Administrator")

Comment: It worked @BittoBennichan .. now I know the problem is in header("Location: admin/index.php");
i tried this: 

if ($type == "Administrator") {
   session_start();
   $_SESSION['user_role'] = $type;
   $_SESSION['admin'] = $name;
   echo "test";
   header("Location: admin/index.php");

Comment: header("Location: admin/index.php"); This is being completely ignored..

Comment: I spotted `extract($_POST)` in your code. Please be aware that this introduces a high probability of security vulnerabilities in your code. It basically replicates the old *register_globals* functionality that was removed from PHP a number of years ago due to the severe security issues it caused.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fixed it: The problem was with the header.. it was not loading it because the output was already started, the solution was to group all the PHP at the start of the page and put the include partial/header at the very bottom of the php so that no whitespace or output can be read before the header executes.. thus the script works perfectly now, I wish to thank you all for giving me guidance to get to this desired solution!

```
<?php
session_start();
if (!empty($_SESSION['admin'])&&!empty($_SESSION['type'])) {
    header("Location: admin/");
}
elseif (!empty($_SESSION['user'])&&!empty($_SESSION['type'])) {
    header("Location: user/");
}
extract($_POST);
                    if (isset($btn) && !empty($username) && !empty($password)) {
                        require 'includes/users.php';
                        login();
                    }
                    include "partials/header.php";
                ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

You already start a session in `Login.php`. Please remove `@session_start();` from `Users.php`.

Comment: Just tried nothing happened, it keeps redirecting me back to login.php

Comment: You are wrong. You need `session_start()` in every file, where you use sessions, called **before** any use of it. `login.php` is not required or included in `users.php` so you need to call functioon again.

Comment: @BartoszT — You don't. You need to call it before you use it in every **program**, not file. The include is the other way around: `require 'includes/users.php';`

Comment: In this case (OP post) the files seems to be separate scripts, not single application.

Comment: Even [examples in PHP Docs](http://php.net/manual/en/function.session-start.php) call `session_start()` on every page, because they have nothing common. In big applications you have preloaded configs, headers, db connections and etc. where you put `session_start()` once, but this file is included by template on every single page.

Comment: Ok, I noticed this require. But my comments are not 100% wrong.

Comment: An additional php file doesn't mean a page on a browser, it may contain configs , parameters, etc. and you can just require it on your main php/kernel php file. What PHP Docs is saying is you have to session start on every page request from server but you don't have to initialize it again unless you close it.